# complex @Aggregation gives me `UncategorizedMongoDbException`

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have some data like this:

```
[
{
  "id": "dc4b9a2f-12b3-42f8-b0b3-dd1bff19fccc",
  "name": "name 1",
  "fields": [
     {"id": 2},{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}
  ],
  "order": [1,3,2]
},
{
  "id": "dc4b9a2f-12b3-42f8-b0b3-dd1bff19fccd",
  "name": "name 2",
  "fields": [
     {"id": 1},{"id": 2}, {"id": 3}
  ],
  "order": [1,4,2]
}
]
```

Now I want to sort `fields` field based on their id, but the order will come from `order` field.

So the final response should be like:

```
[
{
  "id": "dc4b9a2f-12b3-42f8-b0b3-dd1bff19fccc",
  "name": "name 1",
  "fields": [
     {"id": 1},{"id": 3}, {"id": 2}
  ],
  "order": [1,3,2]
},
{
  "id": "dc4b9a2f-12b3-42f8-b0b3-dd1bff19fccd",
  "name": "name 2",
  "fields": [
     {"id": 1},{"id": 2}, {"id": 3}
  ],
  "order": [1,4,2]
}
]
```

Here is the query i’ve written:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
       "{$unwind: '$fields'}",
       "{$sort: {'fields.id': 1, 'order': 1}}",
       "{$group: {_id: '$_id', name: {$first: '$name'}, fields: {$push: '$fields'}, order: {$first: '$order'}}}",
       "{$project: {_id: 1, name: 1, fields: 1, order: 1}}"
})
```

But it gives me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
Command failed with error 40234 (Location40234): 'The field 'id' must be an accumulator object' on server localhost:27017. 
The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "The field 'id' must be an accumulator object", "code": 40234, "codeName": "Location40234"}; 
  nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40234 (Location40234): 'The field 'id' must be an accumulator object' on server localhost:27017. 
The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "The field 'id' must be an accumulator object", "code": 40234, "codeName": "Location40234"}
```

Comment: Is this your real query? The error message does not match to it. The query is working without any error, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/3asHFvFNzQp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$unwind`, `$sort` and `$group`, you may use [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) if you use MongoDB version 5.2 or newer. Should be much faster and much less code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      fields: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$fields",
          sortBy: { id: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KaUHOmOyu93)